# ASP.NET: can't login to site with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am trying open a project for testing locally. I have installed IIS, VS 2015, SSMS 2016 and have opened the site through IIS. I am able to run the default.aspx just fine in Visual Studio (which also works fine regularly). However, the problem is that when I try to login, I get a "Unable to connect". I feel like it may be something in IIS settings like the authorization or SQL Express. I also made sure that the database is connected and edited the web.config. I have tinkered with both for some time now without success. If someone can help point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it you are not connecting to the database? there could be a number of issues there: what type of authentication are you using to access the DataBase?

Comment: Im thinking the same, windows authentication

Comment: In the development environment (IDE) Visual Studio you will be running   the app under your login/user so that will need to be enabled for the Database server and specific schema you are trying to target.
In IIS as the other answer indicates you will be running under what is configured for the appool that the site is using.

Let me know if this makes sense for you or if you need me to give you more specific instructions

Comment: Wow. I've spent what feels like forever trying to figure this out. You understood my question and based off what you said in comments I was able to figure it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Very happy to help. Visual Studio developers have all encountered these issues. 
I will put my comments  in the form of a answer and you can accept it. Maybe it will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You are using **Windows Authentication** for your Database Connection. You should look into both of these scenarios:
In the **Visual Studio** development environment(IDE) (IISExpress) will be running the app under your **login/user** so that will need to be enabled (in SSMS) for the Database server and specific schema you are trying to target.

In **IIS** (as the other answer indicates) you will be running under what is configured for the **appool** that the site is using. So the Database and Schema will need to be configured accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection string.

If you are using `Integrated Security = true` then identity of IIS Application pool will be used to connect to SQL Server. So check in you IIS configuration, under which account the application pool is running. Then give access to the same account in your SQL Server.

Alternatively, you can create a dedicated user login in your SQL Server for the application and use that in your connection string.

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid; Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

HTH

Comment: This is only true if you are running the app in IIS. I think the user wants to know about running it in his development environment.

Comment: Thanks @madcap, what you put did help put things into perspective for IIS and I will more than likely need that info in future but what I needed was to run in local environment